# Prove that regular polygon whose vertices lie on lattice points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a square

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Prove that a regular polygon whose vertices lie on lattice points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a square.

Here is my progress: Say $n > 9$ is the smallest positive integer such that a regular $n$-gon has its vertices lying on lattice points (the other base cases are easy to handle. Then note that $n$ must be prime or else if $n = pq$ where $p$ is a prime and $q > 1$, then there exists a $q$-gon whose vertices lie on lattice points. Now note that the center of the regular polygon must satisfy $O \equiv (p, q)$ where $\{ p \}$ and $\{ q \}$ are multiples of $\frac{1}{4}$ (since $n$ is prime, let $n = 2k+1$ and polygon be $A_1A_2 \dots A_{2k+1}$. Then $O \equiv$ midpoint of $A_1B_j$ where $B_j$ is midpoint of $A_d$ and $A_{d+1}$, $d = \frac{k+1}{2}$. Therefore, the result follows) and since each point is a lattice point, it follows that if $r$ is the circumradius of the polygon, then $r^2$ is rational. Thus, $A_1A_2 = 2r\sin \left ( \frac{\pi}{n} \right ) \implies (A_1A_2)^2=4r^2\sin \left ( \frac{\pi}{n} \right )^2$. But $(A_1A_2)^2$ is an integer, so $4r^2\sin \left ( \frac{\pi}{n} \right )^2$ is an integer which means $\sin \left ( \frac{\pi}{n} \right )^2 = \frac{1-\cos\left ( \frac{2\pi}{n} \right )}{2}$ is rational. Thus, from the counterpart of Niven's Theorem for cosine angles, we conclude that $\cos \left ( \frac{2\pi}{n} \right )$ is rational implies that $\frac{2\pi}{n} \in \left \{ 0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{3} \right \}$ none of which is possible. So the only value of $n$ which satisfies the propositions of the problems is $\boxed{n=4}$

Is this correct?

Comment: $O$ is not the midpoint of $A_1$ and $B_j.$ The center of a regular polygon is closer to the midpoint of the sides than to the vertices.

Comment: However, you can use the fact that the circumcenter is the barycenter (arithmetic mean) of _all_ the vertices, which makes the coordinates of the circumenter rational, which in turn makes the square of the circumradius rational.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Oh yeah my bad. Thanks for the catch. Thanks for the fix. Is the rest of the proof correct?

Comment: The rest looks good, at least I cannot find any issues with it. The "none of which is possible" perplexed me for a short moment (as there are solutions) until I remembered that you assumed $n>9$ in the first place.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Thanks.

Comment: I recommend [Mathologer's YouTube video on "shrink" proofs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDfzCIWpS7Q) for a different approach on the non-existence of certain regular polygons in grids.

Comment: "Please check if my proof is correct" questions typically aren't a good fit for the site format, because asking someone to check an entire proof is too open-ended, and because answers are likely to be either "Yes" or "No", which is unlikely to help others in the future.  Please refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info, then [edit] your question to bring it into compliance with the site guidelines and expectations.